# How to solve ResourceExhaustedError? Why is there such a big tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory

My loss function would be tf.losses.mean_squared_error, but with this, ResourceExhaustedError occurs.
Because of this, I tried to implement the loss function on my own:

```
diff = tf.subtract(ground_truth_ph, self.pred, name='sub') 
loss_op = tf.math.square(diff, name='squared')
```

I still get the error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1138314,1138314] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
     [[{{node sub}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

My self.pred have a shape of (1138314, 1), and ground_truth_ph also (initialized with (None, 1))

I don't understand why is it needed to allocate this amount of memory for an elementwise subtraction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is  `ground_truth_ph` an instance of  `tf.placeholder()`? Can you show me how  it is instantiated?

Comment: Also, please include the rest of your code. It seems like the error you are seeing may be being caused by something other than the 2 lines shown. If `self.pred` is a prediction made by a neural network, it seems likely that making that prediction is where the error is being caused. The 2 lines above would not produce a square tensor, unless passed one.